# If the query value, or part of the query value, is in the array, return true

Tags: javascript, arrays, contains, predicate

I have an employee list containing over 600 names (first- and last name). Based on this list, I need to create an array. I also need a syntax that, based on search queries, browse through this array and returns either *true* or *false* if the search query string is part of the array. The Search query is already captured in a variable called *query*.

Example:

1. Array

   `var employee = [ "John Smith", "Bob Hope", "Scott John", "Calum John" ];`
2. If the query value, or part of the query value, is in the array *employee*, return *true*, otherwise, return *false*

Example:

- If *query* equals **john smith**, return *true*
- If *query* equals **bob**, return *true*
- If *query* equals **SCOTT JOHN FINANCE DEPARTMENT**, equals *true*
- If *query* equals **health insurance**, equals *false*

So basically, if the search query contains any name, return *true*.

Hope this is clear enough. JavaScript is not my prime, so really appreciate all help I can get.

Best,
John

Comment: `const isItThere = employee.includes(name); // outputs as true or false` try using it.

Comment: That would only work if the query is an exact match. If it is "John Smith" in the array, it will return false if the query is only "John"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#some` with `array#includes` by converting your query to lowercase as well as converting the employee name to lowercase.

```
employees.some(employee => employee.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) || query.toLowerCase().includes(employee.toLowerCase()))
```

```js
var employees = [ "John Smith", "Bob Hope", "Scott John", "Calum John" ],
    queries = ['john smith', 'bob', 'SCOTT JOHN FINANCE DEPARTMENT', 'health insurance'],
    result = queries.map(query => employees.some(employee => employee.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) || query.toLowerCase().includes(employee.toLowerCase())));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Hassan! It's getting closer to what I'm looking for. However, the query variable (Called 'query') is independent of this syntax and only needs to be called somehow. Also, would it be possible to capture all this in a function, with a return statement?

Comment: How do you want to pass query, a simple string or an array of string?

Comment: A simple string. The query itself, is stored in a variable called "query". If the query string, or part of the query string, is in the array "employee", return true, otherwise, return false.

Comment: `employees.some(employee => employee.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) || query.toLowerCase().includes(employee.toLowerCase()))` wrap this statement in a function and you will get the result

Comment: Like this? function() {
    var employee = [ "John Smith", "Bob Hope", "Scott John", "Calum John" ];
   var query = {{CJ - Search Term Name}};
    return employee.some(employee => employee.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) || query.toLowerCase().includes(employee.toLowerCase()))
  }

Comment: {{CJ - Search Term Name}} is the Google Tag Manager Custom Javascript variable that holds the query

Comment: Yes. It will work. Just make sure the `search term name` is a valid javascript variable name. But make sure, it is assigned to query variable.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for you help Hassan.